# Installing Windows 7 through Xubuntu from ISO image (no CD drive)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, installation

A friend just received the parts for a computer, and we're trying to get Windows 7 installed. The CD drive that it came with isn't able to connect, so we're having to go down a creative path to get Windows installed.

We don't have a flash drive over 4 GB, so we can't install from a flash drive. We do have a TB external HDD, but I couldn't get the pc to boot from it.

So we installed Xubuntu on his secondary hard drive, and mounted the Windows 7 iso. Our goal is to install Windows 7 on the primary HDD, Windows would fix the MBR, and we could just format the secondary HDD.

So my question is, now that I have it mounted... how can I get it to run the setup file? I was going to try it with Wine but that won't work. Is there any other way I can get the setup going with Xubuntu? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you wouldn't able to install window 7 through wine... In order to create bootable window 7, 4 GB Pen drive is sufficient->[Tutorial](http://npkandel.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-make-window-78-boot-able-usb.html)

Comment: You can get to the setup file with 7zip.  It happily reads ISOs.  Get it from here:  http://www.7-zip.org/download.html.  Not sure if this will help with OS install

Answer (score 0):

Excellent, I have two answers for you!

1. Just go and buy a larger USB stick from which to install;
2. Follow (and tweak as necessary) the instructions here: [Ubuntu Guide - How to install Windows 7 from Ubuntu without burning a disc](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-install-windows-7-from-ubuntu-without-burnning-a-disc)

Comment: @slhck, thank you for the edit. I thought I had formatted it properly. This looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach will be to get your CD Drive to work, boot the Windows 7 CD and install from that. The approach you're trying to follow will consume more time. Isn't time money?